# how to parse Xml data using story board in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing

I am new bie in iPhone.I was study parsing xml data below link tutorial.but this tutorial using i am implement in same project in story board then problem is occur.

I think problem with xmlAppdelegate class.

my problem is how to manage delegate class.And how to manage in storyboard.

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/

If storyboard into demo then please update link.

Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tutorials on the Internet that will help you accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

You have to use [NSXmlParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class in order to parse the xml. There are also other third party libraries to parse xml but i would suggest you to stick with NXXmlParser since there are more help available for it if you face some sort of issues.

Since you have asked for parsing xml and the project have to have StoryBoards, [HERE](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-rss-reader-tutorial/) is a good tutorial to achieve exactly what you want to do and will give you a good head start.

Hope this helps!